# Shortcut conflict (Ctrl+`) between Ubuntu 16.04 and VS Code

Tags: shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I just installed Visual Studio Code and often use the integrated terminal. To toggle the display of the terminal you use the shortcut Ctrl+`. Whenever I use that shortcut, I receive a notification on the top right corner of my screen with the status of my network connection and VS Code doesn't even register the shortcut. It seems as though there is a conflict between VS Code and Ubuntu. I couldn't find this particular shortcut in Ubuntu's keyboard shortcut settings. Is there a way to disable this shortcut in Ubuntu?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? Unity?

Comment: Yes, it is Unity.